# use-package: How to defer loading a command when depending on other deferred packages?

Tags: use-package

I would like to autoload the command `f-join` from [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) using [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). Note that the package `f.el` depends on the packages [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) and [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el). Here is a minimal example:

```
(setq debug-on-error t)
(let ((default-directory  "~/test/emacs")
      (packages (list "dash.el" "f.el" "s.el" "use-package")))
  (dolist (package packages)
    (add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name package))))

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

(use-package dash
  :defer t)

(use-package f
  :after (s dash)   ;; make loading order-independent
  :commands f-join  ;; add autoload for f-join
  :defer t)

(use-package s
  :defer t)

(f-join "a" "b")
(message-box "Everything ok")
```

Running this with `emacs -Q -l` gives error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function f-join)
```

Changing `:defer` to `:demand` on the dependent packages `dash.el` and `s.el` eliminates the error message, but now the packages are no longer autoloaded, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Side note: `f-join` is not a *command*, it's a *function*.

Comment: Could you explain why you want `f-join` autoloaded?

Comment: @Stefan To avoid loading `f.el` in case I did not use `f-join`?

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is: how come you sometimes use f-join and sometimes not?  [ side note: instead of `(f-join A B)` you can use `(expand-file-name B A)` without needing any extra library.  `f-join` here only saves you a few keystrokes, and costs you extra processing.  ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `:after (s dash)`, they will be required while loading `f.el`.

By using `M-x emacs-lisp-macroexpand`, you can expand your `use-package` use into

```
(progn
  (defvar use-package--warning281
    #'(lambda
        (keyword err)
        (let
            ((msg
              (format "%s/%s: %s" 'f keyword
                      (error-message-string err))))
          (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (eval-after-load 'dash
        '(eval-after-load 's
           '(unless
                (fboundp 'f-join)
              (autoload #'f-join "f" nil t))))
    (error
     (funcall use-package--warning281 :catch err))))
```

So `f-join` is not autoloaded in time.